# (Ionic Deploy) My App Starting Screen is Very Slow Open

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

My project is very slowly opening with Ionic Deploy.

Starting time (Without Ionic Deploy): 00:09 seconds

Starting time (With Ionic Deploy): 00:24 seconds

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Why is this happening? Is this happening to you too?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading the deploy update during app startup, that can slow down start times. The Ionic Deploy service must check if there's an update, download the update and then unzip it.

The other options would be to 1) download/unzip the update during app usage and then show users the update next time they open the app or 2) write a custom installation scenario. I would suggestion option 1.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/deploy/